# Why does Community suggest edits?

Tags: discussion

Today, a suggested edit was:

[image]

Why does Community *suggest* edits?

I thought Community edits were applied immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community's just a bot, it has no agency.  What you're seeing here is one of the uses of Community, it's a stand-in for actions that an anonymous user took.  An anonymous user suggested an edit to that question.  It went to the review queue where it was accepted, and then it was applied to the post.  Since the SE platform needs *someone* to have done the edit, it uses Community.